# Mysql table running out of ids

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have a mysql table that is running out of ids soon (the primary id is a 32-bit integer and the max id is already about 1.5 billion). What is the best way to fix this issue? Alter the id type to 64-bit is an option but that would bring down the database for too long because the table has billion of rows.

Comment: What is the actual datatype of that column used in your schema

Comment: Let's talk about what you are doing to run out of ids.  Do you have 1.5 billion rows?  Or are most of the ids deleted?  Burned?  Otherwise lost?  It _may_ be possible to slow down the consumption so that you won't run out.

Answer (score 3):

All versions of MYSQL (both 32bit and 64bit) use an 8 byte field for a column defined as BIGINT.

So amend the column to be BIGINT

[Check the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: As stated in my question, amend the column type of such a big table would require a very long down time for our db server.

Comment: Well it does not look like you have the option of doing nothing.

Answer (score 3):

then try changing the type of the field. Try some type with a big range like "`BIGINT`".